# My Pygame messagetoscreen function doesnt show text

Tags: python, function, fonts, pygame

I am following a youtube tutorial series, and I came across this problem with my pygame game. I made a function called messagetoscreen, and it works fine in the video, but it doesn't work for me.

Here is my code:

```
#Imports

import pygame
pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()
import sys
import random
import cx_Freeze
import time

#Variables

playerhealth = 100

black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
red = (255, 0, 0)
green = (0 ,255, 0)

windowtitle = "Climber"
sizex = 1000
sizey = 700

rect1x = 500
rect1y = 350
rect1sizex = 50
rect1sizey = 50

rect1xchange = 0
rect1ychange = 0

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
fps = 600

font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)

#Functions

def messagetoscreen (msg,color):
    screentext = font.render(msg, True, color)
    gamedisplay.blit(screentext , [sizex / 2, sizey / 2])

#Initialization

gamedisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((sizex, sizey))
pygame.display.set_caption(windowtitle)

#Game Loop

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                rect1ychange -= 1
            elif event.key == pygame.K_a:
                rect1xchange -= 1
            elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                rect1ychange += 1
            elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                rect1xchange += 1
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                rect1ychange = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_a:
                rect1xchange = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                rect1ychange = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                rect1xchange = 0

    if rect1y > 650:
        rect1y = 650
    if rect1x > 950:
        rect1x = 950
    if rect1y < 0:
        rect1y = 0
    if rect1x < 0:
        rect1x = 0

    rect1x += rect1xchange
    rect1y += rect1ychange
    messagetoscreen("HAPPY", red)

    gamedisplay.fill(white)
    pygame.draw.rect(gamedisplay, green, (rect1x, rect1y, rect1sizex, rect1sizey))

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(fps)
```

I would like to know how to fix my function, and anything else that could cause an error.

Comment: you defined the function.. but where do you use it?

Comment: Im sorry, I forgot to say that when I used it it didn't show up either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that I blitted the text to the screen before I filled gamedisplay with white. Remember to blit text after drawing a background.

Here is the code that draw graphics
in the while loop:

```
gamedisplay.fill(white)
pygame.draw.rect(gamedisplay, green, (rect1x, rect1y, rect1sizex, rect1sizey))
messagetoscreen("HAPPY", red)
```